# Spark 1.6.0 stopping working for HiveThriftServer2 and queries through JDBC with registered temp tables

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

In Spark 1.5.2, HiveThriftServer2 sees and returns temp tables that are registered via DataFrame.registerTempTable API.

However, Spark 1.6.0 stops working for HiveThriftServer2 and this API, where it does not see or return the registered temp tables. For instance,

- Querying the registered temp tables with HiveThriftServer2 through JDBC would fail where HiveThriftServer2 does not see those tables.
- hiveContext.table(registerTableName) fails.

Is there a temporary work-around solution in Spark 1.6.0 ? When would it be fixed ?

Comment: This would be a better fit on dev@spark.apache.org or user@spark.apache.org.  Maybe [a JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/) if there isn't one already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=true`, since starting in Spark 1.6 different users of the thrift server have isolated sessions by default.

See [the upgrade guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-15-to-16) for more information.

Comment: That fixes this issue. Thanks, Michael A.,